# Django: Checking CharField format in form with a regular expression

Tags: regex, django, forms, validation

```
class CapaForm(forms.Form):
    capa = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

Upon form submission I want to check the format of the `capa` field. I want to require the user to enter the capa format correctly as 6 numbers, a dash, and two numbers. (######-##)

```
def search(self):
    capa = self.cleaned_data.get('capa', None)

    if ("\d{6}\-\d{2}" or None) not in capa:
            raise forms.ValidationError("CAPA format needs to be ######-##!")
```

It's currently not letting me submit a correctly formatted capa and throws the ValidationError. I think the problem is I'm trying to compare a regular expression to an object. How can I check the format of the 'capa' the user tries to submit?

*********UPDATE

Everything is working now EXCEPT when I type the wrong format in the CAPA field. I get the error `The view incidents.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` Is this related to the changes I made?

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
my_validator = RegexValidator("\d{6}\-\d{2}", "CAPA format needs to be ######-##.")

class CapaForm(forms.Form):
    capa = forms.CharField(
        label="CAPA",
        required=False, # Note: validators are not run against empty fields
        validators=[my_validator]
        )

def search(self):
    capa = self.cleaned_data.get('capa', None)
    query = Incident.objects.all()
    if capa is not '':
            query = query.filter(capa=capa)
    return(query)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you need a regex validator:
[Django validators / regex validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#regexvalidator)

Then, add it into the validator list of your field:
[using validators in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/#validators)

Simple example below:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
my_validator = RegexValidator(r"A", "Your string should contain letter A in it.")

class MyForm(forms.Form):

    subject = forms.CharField(
        label="Test field",
        required=True,  # Note: validators are not run against empty fields
        validators=[my_validator]
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also ask from both part in your form, it would be cleaner for the user :

```
class CapaForm(forms.Form):
capa1 = forms.IntegerField(max_value=9999, required=False)
capa2 = forms.IntegerField(max_value=99, required=False)
```

and then just join them in your view :

```
capa = self.cleaned_data.get('capa1', None) + '-' + self.cleaned_data.get('capa2', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [RegexField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#regexfield). It's the same as `CharField` but with additional argument `regex`. [Under the hood](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/fields/#RegexField) it uses validators.

Example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.RegexField(regex=re.compile(r'\d{6}\-\d{2}'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex validator does not work for me in Django 2.2

Step to set up custom validation for a field value:

1. define the validation function:

   ```
   def number_code_validator(value):
       if not re.compile(r'^\d{10}$').match(value):
           raise ValidationError('Enter Number Correctly')
   ```
2. In the form add the defined function to validators array of the field:

   ```
   number= forms.CharField(label="Number", 
                           widget=TextInput(attrs={'type': 'number'}),
                           validators=[number_code_validator])
   ```